# Getting error while write into the file using Python

Tags: python, django

I need some help. I am getting some error while concatenating the string using python. The error is given below.

Error:

```
appstr='<location name="'+ re.escape(location_name) +'"><room id="'+ re.escape(num) + '"><roomname>+'re.escape(rname)'+</roomname><noseats>+'re.escape(seat)'+</noseats><projectorscreen>+'re.escape(projector)'+</projectorscreen><videoconf>+'re.escape(video)'+</videoconf></room></location>'
                                                                                                          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am explaining my code below.

```
def some(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        serch=request.POST.get('searchby')
        location_name = request.POST.get('lname')
        rname = request.POST.get('rname')
        seat = request.POST.get('seat')
        projector = request.POST.get('projector')
        video = request.POST.get('video')
        num=str(random.randint(100000000000,999999999999))
        if serch == 'Default':
            doc = m.parse("roomlist.xml")
            root=doc.getElementsByTagName("roomlist")
            valeurs = doc.getElementsByTagName("roomlist")[0]
            element = doc.createElement("location")
            element.setAttribute("name"  , location_name)
            el1 = element.appendChild(doc.createElement("room"))
            el1.setAttribute("id", num)
            el2=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("roomname"))
            el2.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(rname))
            el3=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("noseats"))
            el3.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(seat))
            el4=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("projectorscreen"))
            el4.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(projector))
            el5=el1.appendChild(doc.createElement("videoconf"))
            el5.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(video))
            valeurs.appendChild(element)
            doc.writexml(open("roomlist.xml","w"))
        if serch == 'code':
            file1 = open("roomlist.xml","r")
            flstr = file1.replace("</roomlist>", "")
            appstr='<location name="'+ re.escape(location_name) +'"><room id="'+ re.escape(num) + '"><roomname>+'re.escape(rname)'+</roomname><noseats>+'re.escape(seat)'+</noseats><projectorscreen>+'re.escape(projector)'+</projectorscreen><videoconf>+'re.escape(video)'+</videoconf></room></location>'
            wstr = flstr + appstr + '</roomlist>'
            file1.close()
            wfile=open("roomlist.xml","w")
            wfile.write(wstr)
    return render(request, 'booking/bmr.html', {})
```

Here I need to write the the data into one existing file. Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: You have `'"><roomname>+'re.escape(...)`. You probably forgot about `+` before re.

Comment: @Szymon : it is there check `<roomname>+'re.escape(rname)'+</roomname>`.

Comment: Also, concatenating string is not a good idea. Better use `format` method. https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-examples

Comment: It's inside a string.

Comment: @Szymon : Can you resize it ?

Comment: change this `<roomname>+'re.escape(rname)'+</roomname>` to this `<roomname>' + re.escape(rname) + '</roomname>`

Comment: In fact after `"><roomname>+'` all your `+` signs to concat string is inside the single quote itself. You need to change all of that

Comment: Ok now its working . but its throwing another error `AttributeError: 'file' object has no attribute 'replace'.
`

Comment: This is one of the raisons to not use `+` with string (in fact, the real reason is that is not Python, this is C syntax), you better do something like `<foo>{something}</foo><bar>{otherthing}</bar>'.format(something=re.escape(foo), otherthing=re.escape(bar))`